# Find the remainder when a number is divided by 999 given the following conditions

Tags: number-theory

> Find the Remainder when $123$,$123$...(upto $300$ digits) is divided by $999$

**MyApproach**

This question is of the type when the remainder is divided by $10^n$ + - $1$

I am not able to solve the problem because of type involved and I haven't understood these type of questions.

> Can Anyone explain how to solve this type of problem?

Comment: Where are these questions coming from? This same kind of question, in the same style, just popped up at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1510638/find-the-remainder-when-24242424-upto-300-digits-is-divided-by-999

Comment: @alex.jordan I think jack posted this He was having doubt in the question.He posted in this question comments too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't want to bury you in notation, so I will settle for examples and I hope you will see the implied pattern.

\begin{align}
   1234567\pmod 9
   &=  (1+2+3+4+5+6+7) \pmod 9\\
   &=  28 \pmod 9\\
   &=  (2+8) \pmod 9\\
   &=  10 \pmod 9\\
   &=  (1+0) \pmod 9\\
   &=  1\\
\end{align}

\begin{align}
   1234567\pmod{99}
   &=  (1+23+45+67) \pmod{99}\\
   &=  136 \pmod{99}\\
   &=  (1 + 36) \pmod{99}\\
   &=  37\\
\end{align}

\begin{align}
   1234567\pmod{999}
   &=  (1+234+567) \pmod{999}\\
   &=  802
\end{align}

The verification of that last computation would look like this

\begin{align}
   1234567 
   &= 1 \times 1000000 + 234 \times 1000 + 567 \pmod{999}\\
   &= 1 \times (1 + 999999) + 234 \times (1 + 999) + 567 \pmod{999}\\
   &= (1 + 999999) + (234+ 234 \times 999) + 567 \pmod{999}\\
   &= 1 + 234 + 567 \pmod{999}\\
\end{align}

So

\begin{align}
   123,123, \ldots ,123 \pmod{999}
   &= 123+123+\ldots + 123 \pmod{999}\\
   &= 100 \times 123 \pmod{999}\\
   &= 12300 \pmod{999}\\
   &= (12 + 300) \pmod{999}\\
   &= 312
\end{align}

For the case $10^n + 1$, it looks like this

\begin{align}
   1234567\pmod{11}
   &=  (7-6+5-4+3-2+1) \pmod{11}\\
   &=  4 \pmod{11}\\
   &=  4\\
\end{align}

\begin{align}
   1234567\pmod{101}
   &=  (67 - 45 + 23 - 1) \pmod{101}\\
   &=  44\\
\end{align}

\begin{align}
   1234567\pmod{1001}
   &=  (567-234+1) \pmod{1001}\\
   &=  334
\end{align}

The verification of that last computation would look like this

\begin{align}
   1234567 
   &= 1 \times (1001000 - 1001 + 1) + 234 \times (1001-1) + 567 \pmod{1001}\\
   &= 1 - 234 + 567 \pmod{1001}\\
   &= 1 \times (-1001 + 1) + 234 \times (-1) + 567 \pmod{1001}\\
   &= 567 - 234 + 1 \pmod{1001}\\
   &= 334\\
\end{align}

Note similarly that 
$$10^9 = 1000000000 = 1001000000 - 1001000 + 1001 - 1 = -1 \pmod{1001}$$

Comment: Why you multiplied by 100 i.e"100 .123"?.. and what will be the approach when we divide by 101?

Comment: @jack I think 100 group of 3 digits are added.So,It is multiplied by 100.I don't know what will be approach when we divide it by 101or 1001

Comment: @Steven Gregory Please explain the approach for the N to be divided by 1001?

Comment: I multiplied by 100 because there are 100 occurrences of 123. I did not divide by 1001. I broke 12300 into two groups of "three": 012 and 300, then added the two groups.

Comment: @StevenGregory Thanku Very Nice Explanation.+1

Comment: @StevenGregory Are you available on chat?

Comment: @StevenGregory Is this correct I have some doubt?
792379237923 upto 400 digits when divided by 101 leaves remainder?
I did like this 23-79=-56
101-56=45
I am getting ans as 45
But the ans is 56

Comment: Similarly I did Q 345345345 upto 300 digits when divided by 1001?Acc to me Ans should be 345.but the Ans is 0

Comment: Yes, I am very sure that I am correct. Please make sure that you are not committing an off-by-one error.

Comment: @StevenGregory Sir can you check how i solved above 7923....?And also 345345.....

Answer (score 2):

HINT: Let $a_n$ be the $3n$-digit number consisting of $n$ blocks of $123$, so that the number in the question is $a_{100}$. Then

$$a_n=1000a_{n-1}+123=999a_{n-1}+a_{n-1}+123\;,$$

so

$$a_n\equiv a_{n-1}+123\pmod{999}\;.$$

This implies that

$$a_n\equiv a_{n-k}+123k\pmod{999}$$

for $0\le k\le n$. What happens if you take $k=n$?

Answer (score 2):

Since $1000\equiv 1\mod 999$,
$$\underbrace{123,123,\dots,123}_{100\ \text{groups}\ \text{of}\ 3\ \text{digits}}=\sum_{i=0}^{99}123\cdot10^{3i}\equiv\sum_{i=0}^{99}123\equiv12300 \equiv\color{red}{312}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Similar to [casting out nines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casting_out_nines) to find the remainder when divided by 9, you can cast out 999's to find the remainder when divided by 999. The reason this works is the same: 1000 = 1 modulo 999, so xyz000...000 = xyz modulo 999. But instead of just adding up the digits, you have to add three-digit groups.

Take for instance the number 12345678. Break this into three-digit groups (starting from the right):

12 345 678

Take the sum:

12 + 345 + 678 = 1035

Reduce modulo 999, using the same trick:

1035 = 1 + 035 = 36 mod 999

So 12345678 = 36 mod 999.

In your case, we have

123 123 123 123=

repeated 25 times:

25 * (123 + 123 + 123 + 123) = 25 * 492 = 12300

So 123123123...123 = 12300 = 12 + 300 = 312 modulo 999.

Comment: How u get p which is repeated $25$ times?

Comment: what do you mean by "p which is repeated 25 times?"

Comment: 123 123 123 123p=

repeated 25 times   I mean this?How it came 123p?How you know it is repeated 25 times.

Comment: Just a typo, I will edit it, sorry

Comment: Why are you repeating it $25$ times?

Comment: Each group of digits is 3 in size and 4 of them puts a total of 12 and multiply by 25 you get 300 digits of that pattern

Comment: 123,123,123,123 3 in size and 4 groups.And why 25?

Comment: 25*12 = 300 and that is why.  Your question asks for 300 digits