# Find the Remainder when $24242424$.... upto $300$ digits is divided by $999$?

Tags: number-theory

> Find the Remainder when $24242424$.... upto $300$ digits is divided by $999$?

**MyApproach**

I did grouping of 3 digit starting from right and added them and I stopped till my number gets less than $999$.

$2424242400$/$999$=$400$+$242$+$424+2=$1068$/$999$=$068$+$1$=$69$

> Why I am getting wrong Ans?Please correct me if I am wrong?

Comment: I can make no sense of what you did, I’m afraid. Can you explain your reasoning? You might want to look at the answers to [this very similar question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1508995/find-the-remainder-when-a-number-is-divided-by-999-given-the-following-condition) for ideas.

Comment: Um, 24242424... 300 doesn't equal 2424242400 which doesn't equal 1068.

Comment: Um... your explanation doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @fleablood   I followed the question this :http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1508995/find-the-remainder-when-a-number-is-divided-by-999-given-the-following-condition and did wrong.

Comment: Where are these questions coming from? This same kind of question, in the same style, came up yesterday at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1508995/find-the-remainder-when-a-number-is-divided-by-999-given-the-following-condition

Answer (score 5):

Since $1000\equiv1$ mod $999$, then you have $$424\cdot1000^0+\cdot242\cdot1000^1+424\cdot1000^2+\cdots\equiv424+242+424+\cdots$$ So it's the same as $50$ copies of $424+242=666$.

Now reduce $50\cdot666=48\cdot666+2\cdot666\equiv2\cdot666\equiv333$.

Comment: @alex.jorden 50⋅666=48⋅666+2 your last step is not understood by me?Why you reduced

Comment: Your approach is right.But Why I am wrong?A similar question was explained here in your comments

Comment: @Jack The 48 has a factor of $3$ in it, and the $666$ has a factor of $333$. So together, that part is divisible by $999$, and therefore equivalent to $0$.