# Find the Remainder when $792379237923$...upto 400 digits is divided by $101$?

Tags: number-theory

> Find the Remainder when $792379237923\ldots$upto 400 digits is divided by $101$?

**MyApproaach**

when ($792379237923\ldots$400 digts)/$101$=

I learned this approach that I have to  calculate(let say U)=Is the sum all of all the alternate groups starting with the rightmost

and (let say)Th=Is the the sum all of all the alternate groups starting with the second rightmost

Rem(U-Th)/$101$=?

But I am not following how to calculate U and Th

> Can anyone guide me how to approach this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Let $N$ be the number. Then we really want to find $N \pmod {101}$.

Note that $N=7923\cdot10^{396}+7923\cdot10^{392}+\cdots+7923$.

Next note that $7923\equiv 45 \pmod {101}$

Also, for example, $10^{100}=100^{50}\equiv(-1)^{50}\equiv 1 \pmod {101}$

We get the same result for each term, and there are $100$ of these terms so $N\equiv 45\cdot 100\equiv 56$.

Answer (score 3):

Since $100\equiv-1$ mod $101$, your number, mod $101$ is:$$-79+23-79+23-\cdots$$ which is $100$ copies of $-56$. And mod $101$, that makes $56$.

Comment: @alex.jorden can you look at this question too http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1510638/find-the-remainder-when-24242424-upto-300-digits-is-divided-by-999

Comment: @alex.jorden $7923$%$10$=-$79$?How

Comment: All mod $101$: $100^0\equiv1$. $100^1\equiv-1$. $100^2\equiv1$ and so on. So $23\cdot100^0+79\cdot100^1+23\cdot100^2+\cdots\equiv23-79+23-\cdots$.

Comment: Actually I don't understand your question. I didn't say $7923\%10$ is $-79$. It's more like I said $7900\%101$ is $-79$.

Comment: It's a typo, in your first line

Comment: @Charc248 Thanks! Others rejected your suggested edit but I implemented it.