# Calculate Remainder when N is divided by $100$

Tags: number-theory

> How to calculate Remainder when a Number $73$^$382$ is divided by $100$?

**MyApproach**

I dont have approach for these type of modal questions.Can Anyone guide me how to approach the problem?

Comment: you can get some idea.... http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1510653/find-the-remainder-when-792379237923-upto-400-digits-is-divided-by-101

Comment: Euler's theorem will do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a slightly different answer than "lab bhattacharjee". Which one of us made a mistake?

Given that $73^{20}\equiv 1\pmod{100}$ and $73^{382}=73^{20\cdot 19+2}$ so

$$
\begin{align*} 
73^{382}\pmod{100}&\equiv [73^{20}\pmod{100}]^{19}\cdot [73^2\pmod{100}]\\
&\equiv 73^2\pmod{100}\\
&\equiv 29\pmod{100}.
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: It is congruent to $29$.

Comment: @Laars helenius Are you available in chat.I got similar question in which I applied Your Concept.But I am not getting correct Ans.

Comment: Hi jack! I am sorry that I had went to bed after my answer and missed your message about a chat. I am available now if you are still interested.

Answer (score 2):

We use Euler's Theorem. The calculation may not be suited to your needs.

By Euler's Theorem, $73^{20}\equiv 1\pmod{25}$.

Also, $73^2\equiv 1\pmod{4}$, so $73^{20}\equiv 1\pmod{100}$.

It follows that $73^{380}\equiv 1\pmod{100}$, and therefore $73^{382}\equiv 73^2\equiv 29\pmod{100}$.

Answer (score 1):

As $73^2=5329,$

$73^{382}=(5330-1)^{191}=(-1+5330)^{191}\equiv(-1)^{191}+\binom{191}1(-1)^{191-1}\cdot5330^1\pmod{100}$

As $191\cdot533\equiv3\pmod{10},$

$$191\cdot5330\equiv30\pmod{100}$$

Comment: Did you lose the $(-1)^{191}$ in the middle of your second line? It would make your answer agree with Andre and Laars.

Comment: @alex.jordan, $$(-1)^{191}+\binom{191}1(-1)^{191-1}\cdot5330^1=-1+191\cdot5330=-1+30=?$$

Comment: Your display makes it read as if $30$ is your final stated answer.

Comment: @alex.jordan, I did want to leave something for the OP

Comment: That's fine, but using display mode math at the end has the effect of making it sound like you are saying $30$ is the answer. If that last part were left in inline math mode, your intent would be more clear.